# Serialize nullable type to optional non-nillable element

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I have an xsd schema with an optional element (`minOccurs=0`, `maxOccurs=1`) of type `int`. The element is NOT defined as nillable. In the data model I would like to map this to a field of .net type `Nullable<int>`, where a `null` value should correspond to the element being omitted in the xml.

However, using the `XmlSerializer`, it seems I *have* to declare a nullable field in the datamodel with `[XmlElement IsNullable=true]`. If I set `IsNullable=false`, I get the exception "*IsNullable may not be set to 'false' for a Nullable type."IsNullable may not be set to 'false' for a Nullable type. Consider using 'System.Int32' type or removing the IsNullable property from the XmlElement attribute.*" But if I understand correctly, setting `IsNullable=true` (or leaving the attribute out) is implicitly setting the element to nillable, and thereby changing the schema.

This is schema-first design, so I can't just add 'nillable' to the elements in the schema.

How do I map nullable .net types to non-nillable xml elements?

(I understand that I can omit nil-elements when serializing to xml by using XxxSpecified properties in the data model, but this approach still requires adding nillable to the xsd schema, as far as I can tell.)

**Edit**: Thanks to the comments I now understand the problem better. There is really two separate issues:

1. Schema-to-code generators like xsd.exe creates a non-nullable
   type in the generated model if the schema element is non-nillable
   (even if it is optional). Can I override this (using any known code
   generator) so I get nullable types in the generated code?
2. XmlSerializer requires nullable types in the data model to have
   `[XmlElement IsNullable=true]`, which means the model implicitly adds
   'nillable' to the schema. Can I avoid this?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you generating the xsd from code, or vice versa, or neither?

Comment: I'm generating code from XSD. My problem is: I cant figure out if it is possible to map a nullable type in C# map to a non-nillabale element in the xml. Since this is schema-first design, I cannot just add 'nillable' to the elements in the schema.

Comment: Uh. I didn't make my question clear enough. Are you generating code from XSD with the automatic tool XSD.exe, or writing it manually? If the former, your only solution is to add some sort of pre-processing or post-processing step, because XSD.exe does not support what you want. If the latter, your options are much wider.

Comment: Actually, I'm using Xsd2Code to generate the code, so I can to some extend modify how the code is generated. But I'm not sure how to solve the problem even with hand-crafted code, without introducing nillable elements.

Comment: Have you thought about writing your own serializer using the FormatterServices object and the System.Reflection namespace?

I have an example, but it is non-trivial.  I've spent many years working out this problem, but that is for myself.  If you have specific requirements you'll need to describe them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also encountered with this problem some time ago. I solved it by introducing additional property that handles serialization logic.

1. Firstly you mark your original property with [XmlIgnore] attribute to exlude it from serialization/deserialization.

   ```
   // Mark your original property from serialization/deserialization logic
   [XmlIgnore]
   public int? OriginalProperty { get; set; }
   ```
2. Then add the additional property and mark it with [XmlElement("YourElementName")] attribute to handle serialization logic.

   ```
   // Move serialization logic to additional string property
   [XmlElement("OriginalPropertyXmlElement")]
   public string OriginalPropertyAsString
   {
       get
       {
           //...
       }
       set
       {
           //...
       }
   }
   ```
3. On deserialization it will:

   ```
   set
   {
       // Check the field existence in xml
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
       {
           // Set the original property to null
           this.OriginalProperty = default(int?);
       }
       else
       {
           // Get value from xml field
           this.OriginalProperty = int.Parse(value);
       }
   }
   ```
4. On serialization:

   ```
   get
   {
       if (this.OriginalProperty.HasValue)
       {
           // Serialize it
           return this.OriginalProperty.ToString();
       }
       else
       {
           // Don't serialize it
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
5. The example could look like:

   ```
   [XmlRoot("scene")]
   public class Scene
   {
       [XmlIgnore]
       public int? ParentId { get; set; }

       [XmlElement("parent_id")]
       public string ParentIdAsString
       {
           get
           {
               return this.ParentId.HasValue ? this.ParentId.ToString() : null;
           }

           set
           {
               this.ParentId = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? int.Parse(value) : default(int?);
           }
       }
   }
   ```

It's pretty simple and you don't have to write your own serializer nor hacking xsd nor other stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure about XxxSpecified, but you can use the ShouldSerializeXxx methods. These happily work whether the property type is nullable or not. The following should do the job:

```
public int? Property { get ; set ; }

// this member is used for XML serialization
public bool ShouldSerializeProperty () { return Property.HasValue ; }
```

As for the generation of code from XSD schema, if you're using Microsoft's xsd.exe tool the best bet seems to be to post-process the generated assembly with e.g. Mono.Cecil to modify the types of the properties of interest and to insert any extra serialization-related members like `ShouldSerializeXxx`. Adding an XSLT pre-processing step to run xsd.exe on a 'fixed' schema with nillable element declarations achieves the first goal, but not the second. xsd.exe is not flexible enough to do what you want. You might also try adding this functionality to xsd2code, since it's open-source.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is equivalent to having an [XmlElement IsNullable=true] attribute on the property, thereby allowing nil element in the generated and consumed xml, which in turn means I'm deviating from the xsd schema. But since I can avoid outputting nil elements, it may be an acceptable solution.

Comment: No, it's not equivalent. `[XmlElement (IsNullable=true)]` has no effect on properties the type of which is already `Nullable<>`, because it is already implied by the property's type. You cannot even set `IsNullable=false` in this case: `XmlSerializer` will throw an exception. You are right that this declaration allows the serializer to consume a nil XML element, but if the XML conforms to your XSD schema there shouldn't be any, so I don't see where the problem is on this side.